# How do you get the content type of an uploaded file using CGI::Application?

Tags: perl, cgi-application

I am trying to process an uploaded file in a Perl program, using CGI::Application.  I need to get the content type of the uploaded file.  From what I read, the following should work, but it doesn't for me:

```
my $filename = $q->param("file");
my $contenttype = $q->uploadInfo($filename)->{'Content-Type'};
```

As it turns out, `$q->uploadInfo($filename)` returns `undef`.  So does `$q->uploadInfo("file")`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You trust whatever did the upload to give you a good content type?  I just save the uploaded file to disk and do:

```
chomp(my $mime_type = qx!file -i $uploaded!);
$mime_type =~ s/^.*?: //;
$mime_type =~ s/;.*//;
```

though you could use File::Type, File::MMagic, or File::MimeInfo instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking for anything that might have gone wrong?

I got that exact code to work just fine, but looking at it, it's wrapped in a test for `$filename` being undef and also for anything in `$cgi->cgi_error()`. My memories are a bit dim but there must have been a reason for that...

Comment: I do know that $filename is not undef, since I am printing that out in a log statement before I try to read the mime type.  I didn't check cgi_error(), but I will try that.  In any case, File::Type worked well for me, and I like that it doesn't rely on the client to provide the type.